# How to achieve Clickable on each image inside the viewpager in Android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, clickable-image

I am new to Android studio and I been learning viewpager to create a image slider.
My image slider has 4 image in each slide. I had tried view.setOnclick in the adapter but it only setting the click on the entire the slide (not on each image). I also tried getting the each image by id and tried to clickable but not working.

Here is my code:

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewPager viewPager;
    Adapter adapter;
    List<Model> models;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        models = new ArrayList<>();
        models.add(new Model(R.raw.black,R.raw.captain,R.raw.lone,R.raw.iron));
        models.add(new Model(R.raw.iron,R.raw.lone,R.raw.black,R.raw.captain));


        adapter = new Adapter(models, this);

        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager1);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Adapter.java:

```
public class Adapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private List<Model> models;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Context context;

    public Adapter(List<Model> models, Context context) {
        this.models = models;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return models.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, container, false);

        ImageView image1,image2,image3,image4;

        image1 = view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        image2 = view.findViewById(R.id.image1);
        image3 = view.findViewById(R.id.image2);
        image4 = view.findViewById(R.id.image3);

        image1.setImageResource(models.get(position).getImage());
        image2.setImageResource(models.get(position).getImage1());
        image3.setImageResource(models.get(position).getImage2());
        image4.setImageResource(models.get(position).getImage3());

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(position == 0) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setTitle("Alert").setMessage("Hi").setCancelable(true);
                    alert.show();
                } else if(position == 1) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setTitle("Alert").setMessage("Hi 2").setCancelable(true);
                    alert.show();
                }
            }
        });

        container.addView(view,0);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        container.removeView((View)object);
    }
```

Model.java:

```
public class Model {

    private int image;
    private int image1;
    private int image2;
    private int image3;

    public Model(int image, int image1,int image2,int image3) {
        this.image = image;
        this.image1 = image1;
        this.image2 = image2;
        this.image3 = image3;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public int getImage1() {
        return image1;
    }

    public void setImage1(int image1) {
        this.image1 = image1;
    }

    public int getImage2() {
        return image2;
    }

    public void setImage2(int image2) {
        this.image2 = image2;
    }

    public int getImage3() {
        return image3;
    }

    public void setImage3(int image3) {
        this.image3 = image3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
view.setOnClickListener(...
```

set `OnClickListener` to every image you have

```
image1.setOnClickListener(...
image2.setOnClickListener(...
image3.setOnClickListener(...
image4.setOnClickListener(...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked. I have another doubt to ask for the design part.. I also new to stackoverflow. can i ask the question as a separate one or can i edit the current post for question in design part

Comment: every question deserves a separated thread and answer (these can be further found by searching and help next generations ;) )